# Is it possible to get an array to show up as text?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, arrays, nsarray

I'm trying to do something like this ..

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello World"];
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObject:string];
[uitextviewOutlet setText:[NSArray arrayWithArray:array]];
```

and I'd like for that to show up on my uitextviewOutlet window, which is an object of UITextView that will print out text.

The code works if I straight out send the uitextviewOutlet object the setText message and if it takes string as the parameter, but it won't take the array.

is there a way to have it take an array?

TIA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can join the elements with, let's say a comma like this: `NSString *joinedString = [array1 componentsJoinedByString:@","];`

**Edit_: I'm not a friend of "Do it for me", but here you go:**

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello World"];
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObject:string];
[uitextviewOutlet setText:[array componentsJoinedByString:@","]];
```

By the way, your code makes no sense, or do you fill up the array with more than just one value?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not as good with this as I'd like to be, could you be more specific and explain what you would do, using my code if possible.

Comment: Hey, thank you. I did not mean to sound arrogant or like I wanted you to do it for me, I just had a hard time seeing what you were trying to say. Forgive me, my objective c is still in development. Thank you for taking the time to write it out for me.

Comment: It's ok ;-) I started with Obj-C the exact same way :D

Answer (score 1):

You can convert an array to a string with `-componentsJoinedByString:` as in @BjörnKaiser`s example. Or for more flexibility you can do:

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello World"];
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObject:string];
for (NSString *araryItem in array) {
  [uitextviewOutlet replaceRange:NSMakeRange(uitextviewOutlet.text.length, 0) withText:@"foo\n"];
  [uitextviewOutlet replaceRange:NSMakeRange(uitextviewOutlet.text.length, 0) withText:arrayItem];
}
```